# Parse error in a do block

Tags: haskell

I am a haskell dummy. I am trying to request the user for seconds and then display the hours, minutes and seconds. Here is my code:

```
prompt x = do
    putStrLn x
    number <- getLine
    return number

main = do
    number <- prompt " Please input a number: "
    seconds <- read number :: Int
    let hours = seconds / 3600
        remaining_seconds = seconds mod 3600
        minutes = remaining_seconds/60
        final_seconds = remaining_seconds `rem` 60 
    putStr (hours)
```

However, I have an error at this `remaining_seconds = seconds mod 3600`. This is the error `parse error on input '='`
Please help me solve it. Regards,

Comment: Lines 2-4 in the code you posted have wrong indentation, which should cause a compilation error different from the one you got. That suggests you didn't paste your code exactly as you tested it. If so, please edit your question so that the code matches exactly what you have in your source file.

Comment: There is at least one problem in your indentation, the code below `do` in the `prompt` definition should be indented. If I try to compile the code after fixing that I get a series of other errors, at least some of which are related to `seconds` being of type `Int` and afterwards used with `/` (which needs `Fractional` values => use `fromIntegral` if you want `/` or better use `div`).

Comment: @duplode: If I try to compile his code after copy-pasting, I get exactly the error he mentions.

Comment: I have rectified the indentation error.That was during pasting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok here are the parts you need to do in order to get it compiling/running:

- remove the intendation problem in prompt
- `seconds` / `read` is not an `IO` action so use `let`/ `=`
- use `div` instead of `/`
- `mod` here needs to be put into backticks
- `putStr` expects an `String` so either add `show` or use `print`

---

```
module Main where

prompt x = do
  putStrLn x
  number <- getLine
  return number

main = do
    number <- prompt " Please input a number: "
    let seconds = read number :: Int
        hours = seconds `div` 3600
        remaining_seconds = seconds `mod` 3600
        minutes = remaining_seconds `div` 60
        final_seconds = remaining_seconds `rem` 60 
    print hours
```

---

btw: I would refactor it into this:

```
module Main where

prompt :: String -> IO Int
prompt x = do
  putStrLn x
  number <- getLine
  return $ read number

main :: IO ()
main = do
    seconds <- prompt " Please input a number: "
    let (minutes,seconds') = seconds `divMod` 60
        (hours',minutes') = minutes `divMod` 60
    putStrLn $ show hours' ++ ":" ++ show minutes' ++ ":" ++ show seconds'
```

Comment: There is another problem not mentioned in this answer, and invisible unless you click "edit" to get the raw source from the question: his indentation in `main` looks like `main = do\n\tlet foo = ...\n\t\tbar = ...`. This will only render correctly with four-space tabstops; since the compiler uses eight-space tabstops it is not correct Haskell. See also [my guidelines for using tabs in Haskell](http://dmwit.com/tabs/), which suggest using `main = do\n\tlet foo = ...\n\t␣␣␣␣bar = ...`; and keep in mind that the majority opinion seems to be that one should use only spaces when coding in Haskell.

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks - maybe you should add this as an answer(?) - to be honest I usually don't even notice as I just loaded the stuff into emacs and fixed the obvious problems (I let emacs take care of the tab vs. spaces thing and I hope it does it correctly ;))

Comment: @Carsten emacs was not involved in fixing this particular problem: StackOverflow itself converted the tabs in the original question into spaces during markdown-rendering. It's a nasty habit that I wish they would correct.

Comment: @DanielWagner ah yes of course ... sorry, as I said I did not even notice, that's why you should probably make it an answer too ;)